# How can I create a formula using xlsx writer

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Hi I am creating an xlsx file 
using xlsxwriter 
is there a way to create an excel formula using this object?

Comment: Please post an explanation of what you've tried so far (ie. a code sample of creating `xlsxwriter`) so that people can better assist you.

Comment: Do you ever bother to read the documentation? xlsxwriter has excellent docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an Excel formula just as you would write a value.

For example:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 2)
worksheet.write('B1', '=A1*4')
workbook.close()
```

Now the spreadsheet cell `A1` has a value of 2, and cell `B1` uses the formula `=A1*4` (which is 8).